# How do I draw over top of a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, paint

I have a `JScrollPane` that fills a `JPanel` (which is the content pane for my `JFrame`). The `JPanel` performs custom drawing - however, it doesn't appear over top of the `JScrollPane`. Should I override something other than `paintComponent`?

Here is a demo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create the frame.
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel custom = new CustomPanel(new BorderLayout());
                // Add the scroll pane.
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
                scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
                custom.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                // Display the frame.
                frame.setContentPane(custom);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

    public CustomPanel(LayoutManager lm) {
        super(lm);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
    }

}
```

Comment: are you meaning one paint done for JPanel in JScrollPane and second on top ???, two separate layers

Comment: @mKorbel I'd like for the paint on the JPanel to go over top of the paint on the JScrollPane.

Comment: the you looking for JViewport

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, that was perfect. I set a custom ViewPort! Thanks!

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776540/painting-over-the-top-of-components-in-swing which also works correctly.

Comment: yes but read the rest questions before and after, strange war, I remember his questions very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like for the paint on the JPanel to go over top of the paint on
>   the JScrollPane

you can to paint to the

- JViewport as you can to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614972/714968) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197261/jtable-how-to-change-background-color)
- use [JLayer(Java7) based on JXlayer(Java6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)
- very similair (as todays JLayer) is painting to `GlassPane`, notice `GlassPane` to `consume()`(by default) `MouseEvent` in the case there is(are) added some `JComponent`(s), `GlassPane` can to covers whole `RootPane` or only part of available Rectangle, depends of used `LayoutManager` and  `Dimension` returns from layed `JComponent`(s)

Comment: @sdasdadas note - use `RepaintManager` for animation and in all cases to `setScrollMode`

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple problem. You are adding the scrollpane to the custompanel which is hiding what your are drawing. Instead, consider intializing your scrollpane with the cutsompanel as its content.

Example:

```
JScrollPane scrlPane = new JScrollPane(customPanel);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will present exactly the same solution. In the actual problem (that's too big for a demo), the scroll pane is third party and contains other components. I would like to overlay drawings on top - but I'm not sure that I can work inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

when you add a single component to a `BorderLayout` and specify `BorderLayout.CENTER`, the component will expand to completely fill its parent.  If the component is opaque, you won't be able to see any custom painting you are doing in the parent.

Comment: I understand that it will fill completely (that's desired), but why won't my panel paint over top? Does the order go 1. children, 2. yourself, or does it go 1. yourself 2. children? If the latter, is there a way to reverse that painting order?

Comment: your panel isn't painting for two reasons: (1) your `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport` is opaque, which hides what's underneath, and (2) your `paintComponent` method draws an unfilled rectangle 0 pixels in size :)  try calling `scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);` and fixing your `paintComponent` method and let me know if that works.

Comment: and yes, a component gets painted before any of its children get painted.  If you want the opposite behavior, I guess you can override `paintComponent` - have the first line of the method be `super.paintComponent();` and then below that do whatever else you want to.

Comment: I don't think those suggestions are correct: the paintComponent method does draw a red rectangle underneath (just not filled in), and calling super.paintComponent() first doesn't work - although I understand it as you do...

Comment: You were partially right about the viewport (see my comment up above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked (as @mKorbel suggested) is to play with the JViewport:

```
scroll.setViewport(new CustomViewPort());
```

where `CustomViewPort` is a class extending `JViewport` that overrides the `paintComponent` method.