# JLayeredPane with a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jlayeredpane

I am unable to make any components apear on a JLayeredPane when adding it to a JDialog.

I have also been unable to find a web resource that shows this may be done in a reasonably sized block of code. Every sight iv looked at "claims" this can be done, and then shows a disgustingly long solution.

What i want is to take a JLayered pane add a Button and place a JLabel with an icon in it onto this pane aswell. In english i want a button with an icon stuck in the front of its text.

That is the awt Button as I have been unable to find a way of making a system looking swing JButton.

Edit: could you help me out with something a little more specific. I think I was a littile to vague in my post.

```
Button button = new Button("ok");
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(null,"Windows",Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog.getLayeredPane().add(button);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"unable to find a way of making a system looking swing JButton."*  See [`UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getSystemLookAndFeelClassName%28%29).

Comment: *"may be done in a reasonably sized block of code."*  Put a number (of lines) to 'reasonable'. *"Every sight iv looked at "claims" this can be done"*  Link to the top 3 pages you looked at.

Comment: single didits would be nice... i find web sights like to post solutions in the tripple digits. Then with a lot of poorly alocated time I find that i can reduce it to 5-10 lines of code myself... just thought I would save my self a few hoursand ask around

Comment: *"just thought I would save my self a few hoursand ask around"*  You should do a couple of hours research before putting your question to SO.  -1 for 'does not show any research effort'.

Comment: "You should be a teacher, you would fit right in with todays education system being the way it is" in terms of 'on question forum grading pepole with no intent to teach'

Comment: *"..with no intent to teach"* Huh.  Where is (any) evidence of your 'intention to learn'?  Such evidence might be seen in linking to 3 of the top pages you had seen, as I suggested in my 2nd comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't seem to have any issues...

```
public class TestLayeredDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayeredDialog();
    }

    public TestLayeredDialog() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                dialog.add(new MyContent());
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyContent extends JLayeredPane {

        public MyContent() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello new world");
            label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            label.setLocation(0, 0);
            add(label);

            Dimension size = getPreferredSize();

            JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
            button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());
            button.setLocation(size.width - button.getWidth(), size.height - button.getHeight());
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyContent.this).dispose();
                }
            });
            add(button);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Remember, `JLayeredPane` DOES NOT have a layout manager.  You become responsible for managing the size and position of the child components, that's the point.

**Updated with new example**

[image]

```
public class TestLayeredDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayeredDialog();
    }

    public TestLayeredDialog() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello new world");
                label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
                label.setLocation(0, 0);
                dialog.getLayeredPane().add(label, new Integer(1));

                dialog.setSize(100, 100);
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The layered pane of the `JRootPane` is responsible for (amongst other things) laying out the content pane and menu bar.  It is also used (in some cases) to display things like popups.

[image]

Have a read through [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

> You can choose to put components in the root pane's layered pane. If
>   you do, then you should be aware that certain depths are defined to be
>   used for specific functions, and you should use the depths as
>   intended. Otherwise, your components might not play well with the
>   others. Here's a diagram that shows the functional layers and their
>   relationship:

Using this, means you are competing with components already on the screen.

Unless you have VERY good reason to be messing with this component, I would suggest you avoid it as 1- It's possible to be changed in the future (the layer position of the components) and 2- It may interfere with other components used by the Swing API

Comment: can I not Use The dialog.getLayeredPane(), oposed to creating a new class that extends the JLayeredPane?

Comment: Yes you can, the question is, should you.

Comment: I didnt realize you could just set the uiManager like that in a global statment. I thought you had to do it spesificly for the component.

Answer (score 4):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629892/230513) seems to work with the following lines added to the constructor:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler(this));
this.add(new JLabel("Label"));
this.add(new JButton(UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage")));
```

[image]

Comment: `LayerDemo extends JDialog` requires a different close operation.

Comment: ya this looks a little better... could you help me out with something a little more spesific. I think i was a littile to vag in my post.

Comment: final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(Elevation.class.getResource("UACicon.png")));
                final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(null,"Windows System Update - Koala",Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.getLayeredPane().setLayer(label,0);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setVisible(true);

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem(s) you encounter. Either of the two existing answers might be suitable. Code in a comment is largely unreadable; ImageIO.read()` might be a better choice.

Comment: sorry im not sure how to post code to this answere box and im not popular enough to answere my own question in a real responce box so I had to make a new question with a better description.

Comment: I migrated the code for you, but you need to work on an sscce. You should be able to edit your own question.

Comment: I think you're getting confused over the use of the `JRootPane`'s layered pane.  There is at least on other component already on the layered pane, that's the `contentPane`.  You might want to have read of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Comment: do you know why my dialog appears blank?

Comment: @blackDog Take a look at [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), you're basically competing for a layer position and losing