# Setting a JButtons Look and feel to the awt.Buttons look and feel

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel

how do i make this JButton look like a awt.Button?

```
JButton button = new JButton("bob");
button.setUI(???????);
```

Comment: I thought I covered that in [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636623/jlayeredpane-with-a-jdialog) almost an hour ago.  Please pay attention.

Comment: I guess i wasnt satisfied with your answere, and didnt want to be rude... figures

Comment: *"didnt want to be rude"*  It is not rude to say 'I don't understand your answer', but many people consider it rude to be totally ignored.

Comment: I don't think it is achieved.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three separate ui Lookandfeel options

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel (“java.awt.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel” ) ;  
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI ( this ) ;
UIManager.setLookAndFeel (“java.awt.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel” ) ;   
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI ( this ) ;
UIManager.setLookAndFeel (“java.awt.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel” ) ; 
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI ( this ) ;
```

If you want to find the installed looksandfeels on your machine:

```
//Get Installed look and Feels
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class InstalledLookandFeels {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf[] = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    for (int i = 0, n = laf.length; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("LAF Name: " + laf[i].getName() + "\t");
        System.out.println("  LAF Class name: " + laf[i].getClassName());
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel (“java.awt.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel” ) ;`  This is not an option (fortunately) for OS X or *nix.  Use instead `UIManager.setLookAndFeel (UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.  Also, that code has 'smart quotes' rather than normal quotes.