# Java LayeredPane LayoutManager add() Method Conflict

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlayeredpane

Suppose I have a `JLayeredPane` called `mainPanel` that is using a `BorderLayout`. I also have a `JLabel` called `backgroundLabel` that contains an image. How would I go about adding the `backgroundLabel` to the bottom layer of `mainPanel`?

```
mainPanel.add(backgroundLabel, new Integer(-1), new Integer(0));
```

The above line seems like the obvious answer, and would work if the `mainPanel` was using a null layout. The `BorderLayout` in `mainPanel` is not liking the command and gives the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
```

How would I go about adding the `backgroundLabel` to the bottom layer of the `mainPanel` without conflicting with the `BorderLayout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [*How to Use Layered Panes: Laying Out Components in a Layered Pane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout), "All of the layout managers provided by the Java platform arrange the components as if they were all on one layer." You have specified `BorderLayout`. Your call to [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-int-) invokes [`addImpl(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-int-). Because `BorderLayout` implements `LayoutManager2`, your value for the `constraints` parameter must be a `String` constraint defined for [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), not an `Integer` having the value `-1`, e.g.

```
mainPanel.add(backgroundLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH, 0);
```

> My intent is for the `backgroundLabel` to be added to it's own bottom layer behind all other components.

Setting a layout on the `JLayeredPane` makes "the components as if they were all on one layer." Instead, set a layout on the component occupying the deepest layer, and add the label to that component. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636784/230513), a label and button are added to each layer's `JPanel` having the default `FlowLayout`.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't ask the question properly.      This would add the `backgroundLabel` on the same layer as the rest of the components. My intent is for the `backgroundLabel` to be added to it's own bottom layer behind all other components.

Comment: Assuming _bottom_ means deepest _z_ coordinate, I've elaborated above.