# Layering Objects (That extend JComponet) on JApplet

Tags: java, swing, layout, japplet, jcomponent

I currently have a JApplet within which I add two objects that both extend JComponet.
Object A is basically a large square and object B is a small square, I need Object B to always be in front of Object A, however I cant work out how to set layering within the JApplet to do this.
Current I am using the follow code, which adds both the items and displays them how I want however sometimes Object A is front of Object B.

```
public void init() {
    add(myapplet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    resize(200, 400);
    B = new Block(Color.green, 10, 10);
    myapplet.add(B);
    A = new Block(Color.red, 100, 100);
    myapplet.add(A);
    myapplet.addMouseListener(this);
    startTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629892/230513), or `OverlayLayout`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513). Either should work in an applet, but this [hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) approach may offer additional flexibility.

[image: JLayeredPane]

[image: OverlayLayout]

Comment: Giving a JLayeredPane a try, the applet will run but does not display anything, my init now looks like: http://pastebin.com/Bct9dVsb

Comment: Too much missing; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this method: [Container.setComponentZOrder(Component comp, int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Comment: I added `myapplet.setComponentZOrder(B, 0);
        myapplet.setComponentZOrder(A, 1);` however I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: component and container should be in the same top-level window`