# Changing ImageImplement image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon

Everytime I change the uploaded image into images array, it draws the image beside the previous image. How can I make the next chosen picture appear over the first one?

```
ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon(images[0]).getImage());
add(panel);
getContentPane().setLocation(200, 0);

setVisible(true);
setSize(800,700);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
```

Comment: setVisible(false) the previous image.

Comment: Nope, because the same code is run when the user clicks to upload another image, so the program doesn't even work from the beggining, if I switch it to false.

Answer (score 0):

you may use JLayeredPane as this allows you to create layers one on another :

[Example][JLayeredPane and painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625495/jlayeredpane-and-painting)

This might help above link shows how to overlap panels u may do it for pictures as well.

Comment: For overwriting on click  event.getComponent() then Component.setVisible(false);

Answer (score 0):

> it draws the image beside the previous image. How can I make the next chosen picture appear over the first one?

Don't keep creating new components. I'm guessing you have code something like:

```
JLabel image = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
panel.add( image );
```

Instead, just change the icon of the current label:

```
image.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```