# Panel over a GridLayout Panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, grid-layout

Is it possible to show a Panel (e.g. Panel-A which is nearly transparent) over a panel that has a `GridLayout` of images?

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JPanel gridOfImages = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));//Panel with a grid of images
JPanel nearlyOpaquePanel = new JPanel(); //A panel that is almost transparent.

// assuming that all already have the required properties like size and colour.

mainPanel.add(gridOfImages,Borderlayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(nearlyOpaquePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

My thought with this idea is that the panels will stack together and the `gridOfImages` will be shown through the `nearlyOpaquePanel`, but my result is that I only got the `nearlyOpaquePanel` to show and I can't see the `gridOfImages` through it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JLayeredPane and painting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625495/jlayeredpane-and-painting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)