# JComboBox disappears when positioned over a JFreeChart in a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jcombobox, jlayeredpane

I have a `JPanel` that has a `JLayeredPane`. The `JLayeredPane` has a `JPanel` which has a `BoxLayout` and holds a `JFreeChart`. The `JLayeredPane` also has a `JComboBox`; see image below.

[image]

The `Graph` object is added to the `chartHolder` at runtime.

When i run the app the `comboBox` display correctly. Once the `graph` object is added to the `chartHolder` the `combobox` stops rendering. Only the graph will display.

If I click in the area where the combo box should be, the dropdown and the combobox become visible. If I click the `graph` to dismiss the dropdown the combo box disappears again.

`chartHolder` --> `DEFAULT_LAYER` in the jLayeredPane
`comboBox` --> `Pallette_Layer` in the jLayeredPane.

Based on the ordering I have provided to the `JLayeredPane`, the combo box should always render above the graph.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

[*How to Use Layered Panes: Laying Out Components in a Layered Pane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout) mentions that "By default, a layered pane has no layout manager." You'll have to verify that you're setting both the position and size of each component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629892/230513) using `setBounds()`. [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) inherits a `FlowLayout` from the parent class, [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), by default; a surrounding `chartHolder` with `BoxLayout` may be superfluous.

[image]

Comment: i tried adding a OverlayLayout to the jLaeredPane. Cant seem to get the comboBox positioned in the right place though

Comment: i added the following code and a overlaylayout. 
        public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled(){
             return false;
         }