# Java catching DOM "mousedown" event through a JFrame.GlassPane

Tags: java, swing, dom, svg, glasspane

Having a GlassPane above an SVG canvas, I can transfer MouseEvents to the SVG canvas with:

```
SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(...)
```

but I can't transfer other events like the one registered by the SVG nodes:

```
((EventTarget) nNode).addEventListener("mousedown", new OnClickAction(cls),false);
```

Has this something to do with Event Bubbling?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709795/230513)?

Comment: In fact yes, I am using the same code than in this redispatchMouseEvent method from the Glass Pane demo. The issue is that this method calls SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent which only transfer MouseEvent. In my DOM SVG application the nodes are listening to Event, not MouseEvent. Thanks anyway.