# Swing: creating a JScrollPane that displays its component centered?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

If you create a JScrollPane that has a viewport larger than the JScrollPane's component, it displays that component in the upper left.

Is there any way to change this behavior so it displays the component centered?

example program below.

---

**clarification**:

I have a component which has (width, height) = (cw,ch).

I have a JScrollPane with a viewport which has (width, height) = (vw, vh).

The component may become larger or smaller. I would like a way to use the scrollbars to position the component's centerpoint relative to the viewport's center point, so if the one or both of the component's dimensions are smaller than the viewport, the component shows up in the center of the viewport.

The default scrollpane behavior positions the component's upper left corner relative to the viewport's upper left corner.

All I'm asking is how to change the reference point. I am not sure how easy this is to do with the default JScrollPane, so if it's not easy, then I'll learn what I can and think of a different approach.

---

```
package com.example.test.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SimpleScroller extends JFrame {
    static class Thingy extends JPanel
    {
        private double size = 20.0;

        @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int isize = (int) this.size;
            return new Dimension(isize, isize);
        }
        @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int[] x = {0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 75, 75, 25, 25, 50};
            int[] y = {0, 0, 100, 100, 25, 25, 75, 75, 50, 50};

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform at0 = g2d.getTransform();
            g2d.scale(size/100, size/100);
            g.drawPolyline(x, y, x.length);
            g2d.setTransform(at0);
        }
        public void setThingySize(double size) { 
            this.size = size;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
        public double getThingySize() { return this.size; }
    }

    public SimpleScroller(String title) { 
        super(title);
        final Thingy thingy = new Thingy();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());      
        add(new JScrollPane(thingy), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final SpinnerNumberModel spmodel = 
            new SpinnerNumberModel(thingy.getThingySize(),
                10.0, 2000.0, 10.0);
        spmodel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                thingy.setThingySize((Double) spmodel.getNumber());
            }           
        });
        add(new JSpinner(spmodel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleScroller("simple scroller").start();
    }
    private void start() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, do post the Code, with which you are pulling your hair :-) . Thank god, for that "I'm not pulling my hair (yet) ", Example will be good, something to try on, will be much appreciated :-)

Comment: I'm not pulling my hair (yet) and you don't want me to post the code I have, but I can come up with an example.

Comment: do you want to paint this snake in the center of the JScrollPane

Comment: yes... although I'd really like to know how to arbitrarily position it.

Comment: wait: no, I don't want to paint the spiral (what you called "snake") in the center of the JScrollPane; I want to paint my component and have my component be displayed in the center of the JScrollPane.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Put a `JPanel` into the scroll-pane
2. Set the layout of the panel to a `GridBagLayout`.
3. Put one component into the panel with no constraint.  It will be centered.

This is the technique used in the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), which places the red/orange image into the center of the parent.

[image]

Comment: I'm think that OP's want to painting something to the JViewport and maybe to set this something to the desired Point

Comment: I don't want to paint to the JViewport, at least not directly -- My real code is a component subclassed from JPanel, as in my example, but it also has other GUI elements in it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson (@Jason S) is common OP with too wide questions :-)

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @Andrew -- you didn't miss the subtlety of the question, it was spot on, it just looked too simple to solve my problem until I tried it.

Comment: @Jason S after you last edit is everything clear, +1 to your question too

Comment: Ahha, I realized my mistake in the morning :( by looking at this answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

I simply added a `JPanel`to the `JScrollPane` to which I added the `THINGY JPanel`. Hope this is what you wanted :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SimpleScroller extends JFrame {
    static class Thingy extends JPanel
    {
        private double size = 20.0;

        @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int isize = (int) this.size;
            return new Dimension(isize, isize);
        }
        @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int[] x = {0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 75, 75, 25, 25, 50};
            int[] y = {0, 0, 100, 100, 25, 25, 75, 75, 50, 50};

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform at0 = g2d.getTransform();
            g2d.scale(size/100, size/100);
            g.drawPolyline(x, y, x.length);
            g2d.setTransform(at0);
        }
        public void setThingySize(double size) { 
            this.size = size;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
        public double getThingySize() { return this.size; }
    }

    public SimpleScroller(String title) { 
        super(title);
        final Thingy thingy = new Thingy();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(thingy);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);  
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final SpinnerNumberModel spmodel = 
            new SpinnerNumberModel(thingy.getThingySize(),
                10.0, 2000.0, 10.0);
        spmodel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                thingy.setThingySize((Double) spmodel.getNumber());
            }           
        });
        add(new JSpinner(spmodel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleScroller("simple scroller").start();
    }
    private void start() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: SIMPLE SCROLLER]

Comment: +1... that works exactly how I want it to work in the horizontal dimension, just not in the vertical dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting your both comments, but

> yes... although I'd really like to arbitrarily position it

there are

- [extract or to create own JViewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614972/passing-current-date)

important methods to avoiding flickering or jumping on the JViewport

JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);

- use [GlassPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715807/layering-multiple-glasspanes-in-a-root-container) (is very simple to set for possition to the desired Point or/and Dimmension)

and

> I don't want to paint to the JViewport, at least not directly -- My real code is a component subclassed from JPanel, as in my example, but it also has other GUI elements in it.

- you can use JXLayer (Java6) or parts of methods from JXLayer implemented to the JLayer (Java7) directly
- could be too hard, but in all cases you can overlay whatever with JLabel

> Notice

all my suggestion to consume MouseEvent by default, J(X)Layer and JLabel with KeyEvents too, but there no issue with redispatch events from ---> to another JComponent

> EDIT
>
> wait: no, I don't want to paint the spiral (what you called "snake") in the center of the JScrollPane; I want to paint my component and have my component be displayed in the center of the JScrollPane.

- your JPanel could be wider than JViewport by default

a) JPanel returns Dimension

b) JViewport return Dimension

- then without any issue, flickering or freeze

a) you can centering Dimmension from JPanel (Point) to the center of JViewport (Point)

b) if is there JComponent you can move the JViewport to any getBounds() tha returned JComponent or Point from JPanel inside JScrollPane

Answer (score 3):

With the suggestion from Andrew, you can't have the view smaller than the viewport (and still centered).

The cleanest way is doing it directly from the layout manager, overriding ViewportLayout. There is an implementation in the source of:

http://www.randelshofer.ch/multishow

Look for the class ZoomableViewportLayout, which does the job perfectly.