# GlassPane is not showing up on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, glasspane

I have been trying to implement a `GlassPane` for my games' in-game HUD, but right now I cant seem to get the `JFrame` to set my `GlassPane` as its own i;ve used `setGlassPane()` and Ive been reading up a few examples trying to find my mistake, but nothing. So I wrote a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates my problem. I have a JFrame to which I add a Jpanel with a label "TESTIING" then I initiate my galss pane and call setGlassPane() on my frames instance. My GlassPane has a `MouseListener`, a `JPanel` and 2 `JLabels`, and an overriden `paint()` however the `MouseListener` wont work the `paint()` wont show and my labels are not there (so basically my `GlassPane` is not being set as my frames new `GlassPane`)-

```
/*Main.java*/

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestGlassPane testGlassPane=new TestGlassPane();
                testGlassPane.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

/*TestGlassPane.java*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class TestGlassPane extends JFrame{
    private GlassGamePane m_glassPane;
    private JPanel drawingPanel;
    private JLabel testLabel;

    public TestGlassPane() {
        createUI();
    }
    private void createUI() {
        setTitle("Test GlassGamePane");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        createComponents();
        //add components to frames content pane
        addComponentsToContentPane(getContentPane());


        //setting glassPane 
        m_glassPane = new GlassGamePane();
        //set opaque to false, i.e. make transparent 
        m_glassPane.setOpaque(false);
        m_glassPane.setVisible(true);

        getRootPane().setGlassPane(m_glassPane);
    }

    private void addComponentsToContentPane(Container contentPane) {
        drawingPanel.add(testLabel);
        contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        drawingPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        testLabel=new JLabel("TESTIING");
    }
}

/*GlassGamePane.java*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GlassGamePane extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private JPanel statusPanel;
    private JLabel healthLabel;

    public GlassGamePane() {
        createGlassPane();
    }

    private void createGlassPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        createComponents();
        statusPanel.add(healthLabel);
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        statusPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 6));
        healthLabel = new JLabel("Player Health:");
        healthLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        healthLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        //Draw an oval in the panel  
        g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }
}
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you have to first add the custom `GlassPane` as your frames `GlassPane` before making the `GlassPane` visible! This code here seemed to work:

```
    //setting glassPane 
    m_glassPane = new GlassGamePane();
    setGlassPane(m_glassPane);
    //set opaque to false, i.e. make transparent 
    m_glassPane.setOpaque(false);
    m_glassPane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Son of a b---. You just won the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setGlassPane(java.awt.Component)

You need to set the glasspane to visible after adding it the JRootPane.

Comment: Lol yeah thanks while testing various methods I moved my `setGlassPane(m_glasspane);` method above the `m_glasspane.setVisible(true);` and it worked would've been easier though if I just read the docs :P

Answer (score 1):

- seems like as Glasspane is correcty created, but Glasspane to overlay only lightweight JComponent otherwise is behind, hidden be heavyweight Swing or AWT J/Component
- Glasspane has not implemented any LayoutManager, you have to set proper LayoutManager
- for testing put non opaque JLabel with some Background
- I m love Glasspane, but you can to use JLayer (Java7) based on JXLayer (Java6) or OverlayLayout, as easiest of ways

Comment: Interesting maybe I will give it a try at least for now I got it working seems I had to set the glasspane to visible after adding it my frame.

Comment: [maybe you have look at shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715807/layering-multiple-glasspanes-in-a-root-container), +1