# Render empty Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have JTable in my swing app. In case if model is empty (row count == 0) I want to show text "0 Results".
How can I do this?

K.

Comment: What is the thing you cannot figure out: how to get the row count or how to display the text? Where do you want to display the "0 Results" text?

Comment: Use a `JLabel`; Take a look a `JLayer` (Java 7) or `JXLayer` (Java 6 or below)

Comment: I'm looking for solution similar to GWT CellTable http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#setEmptyTableWidget(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget)

Comment: which part of it? Keep in mind that I'm not familiar with gwt, so better explain what exactly you want or reference a screenshot ...

Comment: My link was not truncated :)
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#setEmptyTableWidget(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget)
CellTable provides method setEmptyTableWidget(Widget widget) which I  find very usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can to use and to put text (and or with `Icon` / `ImageIcon`) in  `JLabel` to the

- [GlassPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715807/layering-multiple-glasspanes-in-a-root-container) (common and basic workaround)
- [JViewport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614972/714968)
- mentioned [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (based on `JXLayer`)

Answer (score 1):

if you extend `AbstractTableModel`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), you can check the size of your chosen data structure and condition the overridden methods to return a single row and column having the desired value. For example,

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    if (keys.length == 0) {
        return "No results.";
    }
    ...
}
```

Related changes would be required in the constructor and remaining methods `getRowCount()`, `getColumnCount()` and `getColumnName()`.

Comment: If the JTable has 5 columns, wouldn't you get 'No result' displayed 5 times ?

Comment: @aymeric: Only if you do not similarly condition any other overridden methods. The view displays what the model provides.