# Showing GlassPane before entering loop

Tags: java, swing, glasspane, order-of-execution

(In my applicaton with Swing GUI) I want to display GlassPane during some work performed in a loop or method, which is called after clicking JButton.

For example:
(action performed after clicking a button)

```
if (item.equals(button)) {

    glassPane.setVisible(true);

    someTimeConsumingMethod();

    glassPane.setVisible(false);

}
```

Running this code results in not showing the glassPane during execution of someTimeConsumingMethod() - GUI just freezes for a moment, before result is displayed. Removing last line in that loop (glassPane.setVisible(false);) results in showing glassPane after the method is done (when GUI unfreezes).

Is there a simple way to show that glassPane before GUI freezes, or I need to use some advanced knowledge here? (threads?)

**UPDATE1:**

I've updated my code according to **davidXYZ** answer (with two changes):

(action performed after clicking a button)

```
if (item.equals(button)) {

    glassPane.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                someTimeConsumingMethod(); // 1st change: running the someTimeConsumingMethod in new Thread
                                           //             instead of setting glassPane to visible
            }
        }).start();

    // 2nd change: moved glassPane.setVisible(false); inside the someTimeConsumingMethod(); (placed at the end of it).

}
```

The point of 1st change is that setting glassPane visible in new thread right before running someTimeConsumingMethod in my GUI thread was revealing the glassPane after someTimeConsumingMethod finished (double-checked this).

Now it works fine, thank you for all answers. I will definitely check all the links you provided to actually understand threads!

**UPDATE2:**
Some more info: someTimeConsumingMethod(); in my application is prepering  new Swing Components accoriding to the XML data (cards builded from JButtons and JLabels with few JPanels where needed, and adding them in correct places).

<strike>**UPDATE3:**</strike>
I am trying to make it work using SwingWorker's invokeLater method. Now it looks like that:

(action performed after clicking a button)

```
if (item.equals(button)) {

    glassPane.setVisible(true);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            someTimeConsumingMethod();
            glassPane.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

}
```

It works not that good as code from **UPDATE1** (but still - it works). Problems are:

- glassPane loads without .gif animation (file is setted up in custom glassPane class - it works with **UPDATE1** code)
- there is small delay at the end of "working" process - first cursor changes to normal (from the WAIT_CURSOR), and after very short moment glassPane disappear.
  Cursor is changed by the custom glassPane class on activation/deactivation (no delay using new Thread way).

Is it correct way of using SwingWorker's invokeLater method?

**EDIT:** My mistake, I confused SwingWorker with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). I guess the image issue is due to GUI freezing when the someTimeCOnsumingMethod starts.

Comment: Need to clarify. Do you want the `glassPane` to be visible while `someTimeConsumingMethod` is running and then close it right after the function is done?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to achieve. So far I was thinking that cade execution is ordered from the top to bottom (looking at the code in some editor) - when one instruction end, next one starts, but I guess its not that simple. Will try to solve my problem with provided answers.

Comment: In that case, you definitely need another thread to handle some of the tasks. I have given an answer below with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> GUI just freezes for a moment, before result is displayed. Removing last line in that loop (glassPane.setVisible(false);) results in showing glassPane after the method is done (when GUI unfreezes).

this is common issue about `Event Dispath Thread`, when all events in `EDT` are flushed to the `Swing GUI` in one moment, then everything in the method `if (item.equals(button)) {` could be done on one moment,

but your description talking you have got issue with Concurency in Swing, some of code blocking EDT, this is small delay, for example `Thread.sleep(int`) can caused this issue, don't do that, or redirect code block to the Backgroung taks

> Is there a simple way to show that glassPane before GUI freezes, or I need to use some advanced knowledge here? (threads?)

this question is booking example why `SwingWorker` is there, or easier way is `Runnable#Thread`

- methods implemented in `SwingWorker` quite guarante that output will be done on EDT
- any output from `Runnable#Thread` to the Swing GUI should be wrapped in `invokeLater()`

easiest steps from `Jbuttons Action` could be

- show `GlassPane`
- start background task from `SwingWorker` (be sure that listening by `PropertyChangeListener`) or invoke `Runnable#Thread`
- in this moment `ActionListener` executions is done rest of code is redirected to the Backgroung taks
- if task ended, then to hide `GlassPane`
- create simple void by wrapping `setVisible` into `invokeLater()` for `Runnable#Thread`
- in the case that you use `SwingWorker` then you can to hide the `GlassPane` on proper event from `PropertyChangeListener` or you can to use any (separate) void for hidding the `GlassPane`

best code for [GlassPane by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=glasspane), or my [question about based on this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8715807/714968)

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer, I've got some reading now ;-).

Comment: as mentioned @Guillaume Polet and I too, move code execution e.g. `someTimeConsumingMethod();` to the `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`

Comment: You can see in **UPDATE3**, that someTimeConsumingMethod(); is running from SwingWorker right now, which is working with small issues described under the example. I don't know if I am using SwingWorker's invokeLater method in correct way.

Comment: you can to [use this code for simulating any of issues with GlassPane](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049095/714968), there are four different methods

Comment: @TV You are confusing SwingWorker and SwingUtilities.invokeLater. They are very different things but are both related to Swing-thread. Consider using SwingWorker rather than SwingUtilities.invokeLater as I described in my answer

Answer (score 3):

You are blocking the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread, the single thread where all UI events are handled) with your time consuming job.

2 solutions:

1. Wrap the calls to:`someTimeConsumingMethod();glassPane.setVisible(false);` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, this will allow the frame to repaint itself once more. However this will still freeze your GUI.
2. Move your `someTimeConsumingMethod()` into a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) (this is the recommended option). This will prevent your GUI from ever freezing.

Read the javadoc of SwingWorker to understand better what is going on and how to use it.
You may also learn a lot in this [tutorial about Swing and multi-threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: there not reason why thanking, nor me, I'm talking about describtion :-)

Comment: @TV. then try to avoid use the way that you accepted, everything about Swing JComponents (in your case GlassPane) must be doe on EDT, or wrapped into invokeLater, and hard and long running code must be redirected to the runnable#thread, I can show you 1Mio codes where is required to block EDT, but works only in this form, have to calculating with big throubles, nor in case that there is multithreading, caused locked current JVM instance until is killed by using Task manager

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I accepted the answer maybe too early. I will keep it open for some more time and try to get through all materials provided. Please check UPDATE2 for some new info about my time consuming method.

Answer (score 2):

```
 JButton startB = new JButton("Start the big operation!");
    startB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent A) {
        // manually control the 1.2/1.3 bug work-around
        glass.setNeedToRedispatch(false);
        glass.setVisible(true);
        startTimer();
      }
    });
```

glasspane here used here is FixedGlassPane glass;

ref: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Showhowaglasspanecanbeusedtoblockmouseandkeyevents.htm

Comment: this is correct way how to delay desired event out of the EDT, +1 for Swing Timer

Answer (score 0):

Guillaume is right. When you are on the main thread, each line will finish before the next line. You definitely need another thread.

An easy way to solve your problem is to spin off the display of the glasspane in another thread (normal thread or Swing threads - either will work fine).

```
if (item.equals(button)) {
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            glassPane.setVisible(true);
        }
    }).start();
    someTimeConsumingMethod();
    glassPane.setVisible(false);
}
```

That way, a different thread is blocked by `setvisible(true)` while `someTimeConsumingMethod()` runs on the main thread. When it's done, glasspane will disappear. The anonymous thread reaches the end of the `run` method and stops.

Comment: I used your example in my code, check my updated question post if interested.

Comment: Okay, so lets violate the EDT shell we...It would be better to use a `SwingWorker` and turn off the glass pane in the `done` method...

Comment: -1. This is really a bad advice. UI-manipulation should be done on the EDT. @MadProgrammer is right.

Comment: If it's not how you do it, then it's bad advice?

Comment: @davidXYZ You are still blocking the EDT with the `someTimeConsumingMethod`. Try resizing the window while the method is running, it won't work properly, because repaint request are no longer been processed due to the fact the the `someTimeConsumingMethod` is now block the event queue

Comment: @MadProgrammer: in my application whole frame is locked for a moment, when XML data is loading (thats when Glass Pane is visible - blocking input and providing information that application is reading data). Frame is not-resizable. Is it still bad way to do this in that case?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've not actually tried resizing the window. If what you are saying is true, then I'll take note of that. I just knew the display had to be in a diff thread than the method. Anyway, look at the question's update. TV kept the UI stuff on the main thread and method on the spin-off. That works. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @davidXYZ Your assumption _"I just knew the display had to be in a diff thread than the method."_ is correct. But on top of that, everything related to UI must be done on the EDT because stuffs like RepaintEvent, InputEvent, etc... are dispatched on that thread. Eventually, this means that everything that is time-consuming must move off the EDT. For advices on how to do, take a look at the other answers.

Comment: When you open any program and start loading data, do you usually want to be resizing your window? What for???? I wonder why anyone would complain about that. TV, I dont think there's a problem with not touching your frame while data is loading. Can you always drag around MSWord, Eclipse, web browser or any other software while data is loading?? It's funny sometimes what people pick on.

Comment: Please check UPDATE2 for some new info about my time consuming method.

Comment: davidXYZ, for now I am happy with your answer, and I don't think, that your are not right, because it works, but it may be due to the lack of (my) knowledge.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I've learned that today. I didn't know it was always better to leave the UI stuff on the EDT. Thanks

Comment: @davidXYZ the problem with your example is that it is for `someTimeConsumingMethod` and `glassPane.setVisible(false);` to be executed BEFORE your update thread runs (to call `glassPane.setVisible(true)` which would not be desirable at all. The other problem you run into is dirty updates, where one part of the screen is updated out of sync with the rest. You see this a lot when people use table row sorters and try adding/removing the table model out side the EDT.

Comment: @davidXYZ *When you open any program and start loading data, do you usually want to be resizing your window?* is irreverent, you're code will make the program look like it's hung and the user will be tempted to forcefully terminate it. IMHO it looks unprofessional and shabby. I agree, you should provide feedback to the user that you executing a long running task, but to the determinent of the usability of the program. The 1st rule of Swing, is updates to the UI (any part of the UI) must be done on the EDT, the 2nd rule is, to block the EDT.

Comment: @MadProgrammer For the last part of your comment, I think you meant "Do NOT block the EDT"

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Good morning :P Yes, you right, I will have a chat to my fat fingers shortly